# How to suppress onSaveInstanceState using PowerMock

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am trying to suppress `onSaveInstanceState` from the parent class of my `Activity`, but `PowerMock` is matching 2 methods with the same signature in the `FragmentActivity` class which doesn't seem possible.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my setup

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    suppress(method(FragmentActivity.class, "onSaveInstanceState", Bundle.class));
}
```

This is the exception I get back

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.TooManyMethodsFoundException: Several matching methods found, please specify the argument parameter types so that PowerMock can determine which method you're referring to.
Matching methods in class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity were:
void onSaveInstanceState( android.os.Bundle.class )
void onSaveInstanceState( android.os.Bundle.class )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `methods` instead of `method`:

```
suppress(methods(FragmentActivity.class, "onSaveInstanceState"));
```